# Which Pandas version is compatible with Numpy 1.4.1

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I need to get pandas installed on a server on which a couple of people are working.
On this server, numpy version 1.4.1 is installed and it works fine for everyone at the moment.
Unfortunately, the latest pandas version requires a higher version of numpy than 1.4.1.
Updating numpy is not an alternative as there is the risk of creating more trouble on the server.

Is there a way to find out which pandas version works with numpy 1.4.1?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Install a newer `numpy` in a virtual environment

Comment: Strongly second @mbatchkarov's suggestion.  Check out the anaconda/conda distribution  https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/  if you haven't already.  It will make that pretty easy.  So many improvements since version 0.7.3 that it would really be unfortunate to have to go back that far if you could solve the problem with a virtual environment.

Comment: I guess this would not be a news flash to your server folks, but numpy 1.4 is 5 years old.  What sort of refresh cycle are they on?  ;-)

Comment: @JohnE, I am new to that server stuff so I have absolutely no clue what they did in the past 5 years...

Comment: thanks for your. I will check out the virtual environment!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to try pandas [pandas 0.7.3](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fversion%2F0.7.3%2Finstall.html&ei=V_NZVeTFOcOwUaGLgRA&usg=AFQjCNHBCZfV9b8TyFEouaEIDho3eSOLhw&sig2=uJtwRzE_iPHLfU8zMGBGuw&bvm=bv.93564037,d.d24)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is a bit old, but as long as it is working for me I dont have a problem with that ;) We will see!